# facebook connect does not return email address

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using this simple FB connect

```
<a href="#" onclick="fb_login();">Connect</a>
```

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId   : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
        oauth   : true,
        status  : true, // check login status
        cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
    });

};

```
function fb_login(){
    FB.login(function(response) {

        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            console.log(response); // dump complete info
            access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken; //get access token
            user_id = response.authResponse.userID; //get FB UID

            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                user_email = response.email; //get user email
                console.log(response); 

            });

        } else {
            //user hit cancel button
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');    
        }
    }, {
        scope: 'email'
    });
}
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

When I connect, it only returns me

> Object {name: "my name here", id: "102xxxxxxxx230"}

How can I retrieve email address ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email'}, function(response) {
    user_email = response.email; //get user email
    console.log(response); 
});
```

It´s called "Declarative Fields", see changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4